# Running showSidebar in onOpen (Google Docs add on)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm building a Docs add on with Apps Script and calling the showSidebar() from within onOpen().

When I look at the logs, it just shows "error" printed a bunch of times, and it doesn't open the sidebar. Is it possible to call showSidebar() from within the onOpen() function?

Separately, I'm trying to log the user's email from within onOpen() using Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() and seeing that it has no value there. But it does have a value in showSidebar().

I'm guessing I'm not understanding the permissioning with Apps Script, anyone else know?

Comment: Try using an installable onOpen()

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser),

- If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, [User.getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getEmail()) returns a blank string.
- user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a **simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger**, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user)

Hence, you need to use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) which can call services that requires authorization.

---

### [To manually create an installable trigger:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

[image]

**Sample Configuration:**

[image]

---

### Sample Code:

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  showSidebar();

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var email = e.user.getEmail();
  body.appendParagraph(email);
  body.appendParagraph(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar');
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function getActiveUser(){
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
  Logger.log(email);
  return email;
};
```

- I used 2 different ways to get the active user, 1.) Using the [onOpen() event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_docs_events) `e.user.getEmail()`, and 2.) Using `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`.
- Both options were able to display the active user's email as seen in the document where email was appended as paragraph.

**Page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="rangeResult"></div>
    <script>
    function addRange(rangeStartEnd){ 
      $('#rangeResult').text(rangeStartEnd);
    };
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addRange).getActiveUser();
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]